# phpmailer doesn't send emails (security failure)

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

this is the code i'm using:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "server.example.com'";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "noreply@example.com'";
$mail->Password = "password";  
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('to@example.com'', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML("hello you ");
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

this is the error code i get using debug

SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.example.com ESMTP Exim 4.89 #1 Sat, 09 Dec 2017 06:56:21 -0600 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.example.com Hello example.com   [***.***.**.***]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
    SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    SERVER -> CLIENT: ecurity failure554 Security failure
    SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: ecurity failure554 Security failure
    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
    Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

what is the problem here?